Nextjs App Router AWS Amplify, getting error while trying to access current user at server side
Error: Cannot access Cognito.length on the server. You cannot dot into a client module from a server component. You can only pass the imported name through.
import { runWithAmplifyServerContext } from "@/utils/amplify-server-utils";
import { getCurrentUser } from "aws-amplify/auth/server";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

export default async function Dashboard(req:Request) {
  let user = null;
  try {
    user = await runWithAmplifyServerContext({
      nextServerContext:{
        cookies: cookies
      },
      operation: async (contextSpec) => {
        return await getCurrentUser(contextSpec);
      },
    });

    console.log(user);
  }catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
  return <p>Dashboard Page</p>;

